# How to solve the exercise: "Find out if the groups $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ can or not form an isomorphism"?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I need to find out if the groups $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ can or not form an isomorphism. I know that you need to find a bijective function that is also a morphism, but I do not have any idea how to show if there is or not any function. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Any homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is determined by where it sends a generator for the cyclic group. So, where can you send $1\in \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are saying. Can you explain it to me a bit?

Comment: @OvyOvy do you have a specific question?

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by "where can you send 1".

Comment: I mean, if $\phi$ is your supposed isomorphism, the element in $a\in \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\phi(1)=a$

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ shouldn't be a cartesian product like $(x,y)$? Sorry but I am really confused right now.

Comment: there are a few ways you can write it. If it would help to think of $a$ as a vector with two components, this is fine

Comment: the problem is that how can you take $a\in \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Like what do you think a is? you think a is a pair of 2 numbers like (x,y)??

Comment: @OvyOvy Yes, an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is an ordered pair. A homomorphism is a *function*: it sends elements of one group to elements of another. If I have a homomorphism $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, I can ask where $f$ sends (say) the element "$1$" (thinking of the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\{0,1,2, ..., n-1\}$). The four possibilities are: $(0, 0), (0, 1), (1,0), (1, 1)$ (these are the four elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$). Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok but I do not understand what has to do with $f(1)$ cause we can say that $f(1)=(1,1)$ and still we did not solve the problem.

Comment: @OvyOvy $f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0)$ so the kernel of that map isn't trivial. Try another option.

Answer (score 0):

When two groups are isomorphic (let's say there's an isomorphism $f\colon G\cong H$), it means they're essentially the same group; the elements of $G$ and $H$ may have different names, but they'll have the same structural properties.  For example, if $a,\,b\in G$ and $ab=ba$, then $f(a)\,f(b)=f(b)\,f(a)$, *and vice versa* because $f^{-1}$ is also a group homomorphism.  If $a\in G$ where $a^n = e$, then $f(a)^n=e$ in $H$, *and vice versa*; so $a$ and $f(a)$ have the same order (when $f$ is an isomorphism).

Hence the hints in the other two answers: $\mathbb{Z}\mathop{/}4$ has an element $1$ of order 4, so its counterpart in $\left(\mathbb{Z}\mathop{/}2\right)^2$ under any isomorphism $f$ must also have order 4.  Is there any such element?

Comment: Later you'll learn to study the structure of groups by looking not just at their elements, but their morphism to and from _other groups_. For example, you might count the number of morphisms $K\to G$ and $K\to H$ and find that they're different, or similarly for morphisms $G\to K$ and $H\to K$.

Comment: I do not really understand what it means to have the same order.

Comment: @OvyOvy I think that you would be best served reading the basic definitions in the first chapter of whatever book you are reading about algebra/group theory

Comment: Sorry but my books are not in English and maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Also if $a^n=e_G$ then $f(a^n)=f(a)*f(a)*...*f(a)=f(a)^n=f(e_G)=e_H$. So it is not the same $e$.

Comment: @OvyOvy Definitely find a book that is in English. I've never used Dummit and Foote's _Abstract Algebra_, but have heard very good things. "Order of $a$ in $G$": smallest positive integer $n$ where $a^n$ is the group identity, or $\infty$ if there isn't one (not an issue here).

Comment: As for $e_G\ne e_H$, yeah, you're generally expected to interpret $e$ in context.